# Pandas series.all() returns nan

Tags: python, pandas

Here's a bit of code:

```
s = pandas.Series([numpy.nan, False])
s.all()
```

wil return `nan`. Is there any way to make it ignore `nan` in the series, i.e. return `False` for the case above?

I have checked the documentation on numpy.all() (http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.any.html), where it says

> "Not a Number (NaN), positive infinity and negative infinity evaluate to True because these >are not equal to zero."

That doesn't really seem consistent...

Thanks,
Anne

Comment: With `pandas` 0.7.0 and `numpy` 1.6.1 This code returns `False` for me as expected.

Comment: With `pandas` 0.11.0 and `numpy` 1.7.1 This code returns `False` for me as expected.

Comment: `pandas` and `numpy` dev are `False` as well.

Answer (score 0):

As the comments have indicated, the following evaluate correctly to `False` in pandas

```
In [12]: s
Out[12]: 
0      NaN
1    False
dtype: object
```

This method drops `nan` values first, before evaluation

```
In [14]: s.dropna().all()
Out[14]: False

In [15]: s.all()
Out[15]: False
```

I would like to point out this, which is `True` because `bool(np.nan)` is `True`
(I happen believe this should give an error, but thats a different issue)

```
In [13]: s.astype(bool)
Out[13]: 
0     True
1    False
dtype: bool
```

Comment: and also `bool(float('nan')) is True`, agree it's odd... personally think it should be Falsey. Funny this came up again.