# Understand any() and nan in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, nan

I have the same problem as in: [Pandas series.all() returns nan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18021729/pandas-series-all-returns-nan)

```
In [88]: pd.Series([False, np.nan]).any()
Out[88]: nan
```

where as:

```
In [84]: np.any([False, np.nan]) 
Out[84]: True
```

and also:

```
In [99]: pd.DataFrame([False, np.nan]).any()
Out[99]: 
0    False
dtype: bool
```

I was curious what the explanation was for the different behaviors for the three types?

Comment: DataFrame's any is much richer, and has skipna=True by default. Wonder if it's a feature request for Series...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The difference here has nothing to do with the two different types implementing `any` differently. In fact, the docs for [`pandas.Series.any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.Series.any.html) and [`numpy.ndarray.any`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.any.html) both explicitly say "Refer to [`numpy.any`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.any.html#numpy.any) for full documentation", because they both effectively just call `numpy.any`.

The difference is that you have different dtypes in the two cases. Creating a NumPy ndarray, implicitly or explicitly, from different numeric types coerces the types to be the same if possible, so you end up with `float64`, while a Pandas series keeps the types separate, which means you end up with `object`.

If you specify the `dtype` explicitly, you can see that they do the same thing:

```
>>> a = np.array([False, np.nan])
>>> a
array([  0., nan])
>>> a.dtype
float64
>>> a.any()
True
>>> a = np.array([False, np.nan], dtype=object)
>>> a
array([False, nan], dtype=object)
>>> a.any()
nan
>>> p = pd.Series([False, np.nan])
>>> p
0    False
1      NaN
>>> p.dtype
dtype('O')
>>> p.any()
nan
>>> p = pd.Series([False, np.nan], dtype=np.float64)
>>> p
0     0
1   NaN
>>> p.any()
True
```

Comment: @AndyHayden: Yes, but only if you understand what a `DataFrame` is. The equivalent array isn't the 1D 2-array you're comparing it to, but a 2D 2x1 array (as you can tell by checking its `shape`). So, you have to compare it to `np.array([[False], [np.nan]])`. And if you do that, you'll see that they behave identically. (`any(axis=1)` is `[False, True]`, so `any()` is `True`.)

Comment: The result of df.any() isn't the same as any of np.any(df), np.any(df, 0), np.any(df, 1). Ah ha, it's because df.any is much richer (and skips NaN by default.)